# What is EXPERT in kernel menuconfig

Tags: android, configuration, kernel-module

Im trying to install a module 'eGalax, eTurboTouch CT-410/510/700 device support' and its not showing up in my kernel config menu, when I search for it is listed, I suspect it has something to do with the EXPERT option below, how do I enable this?

```
     │ Symbol: TOUCHSCREEN_USB_EGALAX_REVERSE [=n]                                                                                                                   │  
     │ Type  : boolean                                                                                                                                        │  
     │ Prompt: eGalax Special reverse MSB / LSB Packet                                                                                                        │  
     │   Defined at drivers/input/touchscreen/Kconfig:553                                                                                                     │  
     │   Depends on: !S390 && INPUT [=y] && INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN [=y] && TOUCHSCREEN_USB_EGALAX [=n] && EXPERT                                                   │  
     │   Location:                                                                                                                                            │  
     │     -> Device Drivers                                                                                                                                  │  
     │       -> Input device support                                                                                                                          │  
     │         -> Generic input layer (needed for keyboard, mouse, ...) (INPUT [=y])                                                                          │  
     │           -> Touchscreens (INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN [=y])                                                                                                     │  
     │             -> eGalax, eTurboTouch CT-410/510/700 device support (TOUCHSCREEN_USB_EGALAX [=n])
```

Comment: I am seeing a glitch or something Symbol: EXPERT [=EXPERT]  Type  : unknown its very peculiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kernel 2.6.37 EXPERT became EMBEDDED.